# adding space between items, making background not stretch horizontally

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm practicing basic HTML programming and have added a list object to the code between two headings. when I view the list `background` I see that it stretches right to the side of page. About this I want to know how to limit the `width` of background so it ends just after covering the `li` elements (also curious how to get it stretch downward - maybe I need another `div`?)

also want to add some spacing between the `li` elements as shown in a book I have. I have added `liststyle li {}` as instructed but the `ul` box does not respond. it also does not respond to `side / background-size` properties for above issue.

how could I get this list box working?

part of the HTML code:

```css
.liststyle { /* class */
     list-style: square; /* circle / lower-roman  */
     padding : 15px; /*spacing between border and element*/
     margin : 20px; /*spacing outside border*/
     background: #66ccff; /*background box colour */
     color: #ff0000; /*text color */
     list-style-position: inside; /*get bullets inside background box*/
 
     border-style: double;
     border-width: 5px;
     border-color: #600;
 
     size: 100px 100px; /* background stretches horizontally to side of page*/
    }

    .liststyle li{ /*trying to get spacing between list items - will not work*/
     padding-bottom = 100px;
    }
```

```html
<h1>National Geographic</h1>
<h2>How a Remote Peak in Myanmar Nearly Broke an Elite Team of Climbers</h2>

 <ul class="liststyle"> 
  <li>the beggining</li>
  <li>reaching the rampart</li>
  <li>regrouping</li>
  <li>freezing cold</li>
 </ul>

<h4>On one of mountaineering’s most dangerous journeys,  
 group was pushed to the limit by physical and mental challenges.</h4>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- there is no `size` property, exists thought `background-size` (although you don't need this since it is only a `background-color`)
- you have `padding=` should be `padding:`
- you can use `border` [shortand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties)
- to contain the background, you need to use a `max-width` in `ul` + `display:inline-block`
- (extra) adding `box-sizing:border-box` it will make the `border`+`padding` part of the calculations for `width`

```css
.liststyle {
  /* class */
  list-style: square;
  /* circle / lower-roman  */
  padding: 15px;
  /*spacing between border and element*/
  margin: 20px;
  /*spacing outside border*/
  background: #6cf;
  /*background box colour */
  color: #ff0000;
  /*text color */
  list-style-position: inside;
  /*get bullets inside background box*/
  border: 6px solid #600;
  max-width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing:border-box
}
.liststyle li {
  /*trying to get spacing between list items - will not work*/
  padding-bottom:100px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="liststyle">
  <li>the beggining</li>
  <li>reaching the rampart</li>
  <li>regrouping</li>
  <li>freezing cold</li>
</ul>

<h4>On one of mountaineering’s most dangerous journeys,     
group was pushed to the limit by physical and mental challenges.</h4>
```

Comment: thanks I got it working silly of me with the = mistake

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
.liststyle {    
    display:inline-block;
    width:500px;
```

If you leave width param, it fits to the content.